# Issue reading dates with "spreadsheet-reader" in php

Tags: php, excel, csv

I'm using the **[spreadsheet-reader](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader)** to read some `.xls` and `.xlsx` and convert them to `.csv`.

This is my simplified code:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../ext/spreadsheet-reader/SpreadsheetReader.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../ext/spreadsheet-reader/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');

$pCsvPath =  Config::$generatedCSVPath . "/" . str_replace(array(".xlsx", ".xls"), ".csv", $pFileName);

$csv = fopen($pCsvPath, "w");

$pReader = new SpreadsheetReader($pFilePath);

// Read only the first sheet
$pSheets = $pReader -> Sheets();
$pReader -> ChangeSheet(0);

foreach ($pReader as $row)
{
    fputcsv($csv, $row);
}
```

Everything's ok, but I'm having problems with the dates.

There's a column on the `.xls` / `.xlsx` files with the following format `2015-02-10`
When I write them to `.csv`, the output of this column is `2015201520152015-FebFeb-TueTue`.

How can I convert it to `.csv` using the code I post above but maintaining the date as the correct format (`2015-02-10`)?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** If I manually change the dates from `2015-01-01` to `01-01-2015` (put the year at the end) the dates are parsed correctly. If there's no way to save the date as `2015-01-01`, how can I change that row to the correct format (year at the end) using the code I post above?

I know I can parse a date manually, but not using the code above, as everything gets loaded when I call the `$pReader = new SpreadsheetReader($pFilePath)` function and there's no way to manipulate *only* the date.

Comment: Hi, Avion have you got any solution for this?

Comment: Nope, @Kuttoozz, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

use `date , strtotime`

```
date( "d-m-Y", strtotime( "2015-02-10" ) )
```

will going to convert your date format to `10-02-2015`

```
foreach ($pReader as $row)
{

// assuming date is stored on 3rd place , $row[2]

$str = $row[0] ."+_+". $row[1]."+_+".date( "d-m-Y", strtotime( $row[2] ) );


           fputcsv($csv,explode("+_+",$str));
}
```

Comment: Please, read the question. I know I can parse the date using that method, but there's no place I can manipulate the date in the code. As the entire `.xls` or `.xlsx` is loaded when you `$pReader = new SpreadsheetReader($pFilePath)`

Comment: @Borja u have to open your row array , con cat all elements of array and changed date array element

Comment: The row array already contains the wrong date (`2015201520152015-FebFeb-TueTue`), so I can't parse it there. I have to do something before or in `$pReader = new SpreadsheetReader($pFilePath);`.

Comment: can you post output of any row?

Comment: It's irrelevant as you are going to try to parse the date field from `2015201520152015-FebFeb-TueTue` to `2015-02-10` and that would be impossible as you dont know that `Tue` (tuesday) refers to the date `10`.